# How to fire an event right after a radio button is unchecked using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a JS function that calculates scores based on the values of the radio buttons checked. I want my function to update the score field when these checked radio buttons are unchecked later.

HTML:

```
 <input class="calc_1" name="1" id="sec_125" type="radio" value="4">
 <input class="calc_2" name="1" id="sec_126" type="radio" value="1">
 <input class="calc_3" name="1" id="sec_127" type="radio" value="2">
 <input class="calc_4" name="1" id="sec_128" type="radio" value="3">
 <input class="calc_1" name="2" id="sec_129" type="radio" value="4">
 <input class="calc_2" name="2" id="sec_130" type="radio" value="1">
 <input class="calc_3" name="2" id="sec_131" type="radio" value="2">
 <input class="calc_4" name="2" id="sec_132" type="radio" value="3">
 <input readonly name="score_1" id="score_1" type="text" value="">
 <input readonly name="score_2" id="score_2" type="text" value="">
```

JS:

```
function getTotalScore(sec){
   var total = 0; 
   jQuery(".calc_"+sec+":checked").each(function() {
    total += parseInt(jQuery(this).val(),10);
    count++;
});

 jQuery("#score_"+sec).val(total);

}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".calc_1").change(function() {
      getTotalScore("1")
    });
   jQuery(".calc_2").change(function() {
    getTotalScore("2")
   });
});
```

Currently, my code updates score_1 and score_2 fields when a radio button from class "calc_1" and "calc_2" respectively is checked but doesn't change these values when the user selects another radio button from the same input group.

For example, If the user selects sec_125 and sec_130 first, score_1 should be 4 and score_2 should be 1. If the user later decides to select sec_126, score_1 still remains 4 when it should actually be 0.

How can I write a JS function that will update the score fields immediately after a previously checked radio button is now unchecked?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the classes anyway? I would just do it with group names like you already have and forget about the class like `$('[name=c1]')` which I suggest starting with a letter not a number and if you need to know the position use `index`

Comment: I have 80 radio buttons in total with 20 per column. Hence, used classes to calculate the score in each column.

Comment: Maybe you need a different approach... What's `calculateScore`?

Comment: that was a typo, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recalculate everything after each change:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".calc_1, .calc_2").change(function() {
      calculateScore("1")
      calculateScore("2")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind `change` event on all radio buttons

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".calc_1, .calc_2, .calc_3, .calc_4").change(function() {
     calculateScore("1");
     calculateScore("2");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".calc_1, .calc_2").on('click',function() {
      if( ! $(this).is(':checked'){ // Condition When Unchecked
          calculateScore("1");
          calculateScore("2");
      }
    });
});
```